# What is the endpoint URL of the Playable Locations API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to the Playable Locations API and am trying to make my first request.  Based on [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/gaming/using_playable_locations) I'm using the endpoint https://playablelocations.googleapis.com/v3:samplePlayableLocations&key=MY_API_KEY however it returns a 404 error

Is there another URL I should be using for these requests?

**EDIT:** This seems to be related to the way I'm passing the API key.  If I remove &key=MY_API_KEY I no longer get the 404 error. Instead it's a 403 with message *The request is missing a valid API key.*  Am I using the wrong parameter to pass the key?

Below is the code I'm using:

```php
$api_key = 'MY_API_KEY';

$request_url = "https://playablelocations.googleapis.com/v3:samplePlayableLocations&key=$api_key";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do note that though it is already available in the public documentations, currently Playable locations API is **not publicly launched yet**. That might be one of the reasons why you are not able to use it currently. Also, in your Playable locations request, make sure that you are using your own valid API key under your Google Maps project as well as enable the Playable Locations API in your GCP console for you to be able to use this in your implementation.

If you have not generated a valid API key and enabled Playable Locations API in your GCP console yet, here are guides you can check:

Create an API key: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_HZObVbe-g

Enable an API: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1UorU1PALk

Also, it seems you have added the "key" parameter in your request incorrectly. Instead of doing https://playablelocations.googleapis.com/v3:samplePlayableLocations**&key=**

It should be https://playablelocations.googleapis.com/v3:samplePlayableLocations**?key=**

It seems that there is an error in the documentation that's worth filing for a documentation bug in the [Google Maps' Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker).

In addition, you need to have the request body for your Playable Locations API which looks like this:

```
{
  "areaFilter": {
    "s2CellId": string,
  },
  "criteria": [
    {
      "gameObjectType": number,
      "filter": {
          "maxLocationCount": number,
          "spacing": {
            "minSpacingMeters": number,
            "pointType": enum(PointType)
          },
          "includedTypes": [
            string
          ],
      },
      "fieldsToReturn": string
    }
  ]
}
```

More information here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/gaming/using_playable_locations

Comment: Thanks, the issue really is that the API is not yet publicly available. If that's in the documentation somewhere then I missed it but thank you clarifying for me. I guess I'll just have to wait until it's release!

In the meantime I'll go file that documentation bug report.

Comment: How can we get s2sellId based on users current location?